# Performing assertions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, assertion

Say i have a function that computes the sum between two numbers:

```
computeSum :: Int -> Int -> Int
computeSum x y = x + y
```

Is there any **form of control** over the **returned value** from the above function where I only want **to sum up two numbers** where their **sum** will **be non negative and must be less than 10**?

I just started functional programming from imperative where we can have a simple check in imperative programming of a function's return value such as:

```
if value <= 10 and value > 0:
   return value
```

Just wondering if there is something similar to that in haskell?

Comment: [Hoogle is your friend](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=assert).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically ones uses a `Maybe` to specify computations that "might fail", like:

```
computeSum :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
computeSum x y | result > 0 && result <= 10 = Just result
               | otherwise = Nothing
    where result = x + y
```

So it will return a `Just result` in case the assertions are matched, or `Nothing` in case the assertions are not satisfied.

Sometimes `Either String a` is used to provide an error message, like:

```
computeSum :: Int -> Int -> Either String Int
computeSum x y | result > 0 && result <= 10 = Right result
               | otherwise = Left "Result is note between 0 and 10"
    where result = x + y
```

You can also raise an error, but personally I think this is not advisable, since the signature does not "hint" that the computation might fail:

```
computeSum :: Int -> Int -> Int
computeSum x y | result > 0 && result <= 10 = result
               | otherwise = error "result is not between 0 and 10"
    where result = x + y
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Hoogle tells us that `Control.Exception` provides [`assert :: Bool -> a -> a`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=assert).

But you could just write this yourself:

```
assert :: Bool -> a -> a
assert False _ = error "Assertion failed!"
assert _     a = a
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Haskell has if statements:

```
function x y =
  let r = x + y
  in if r > 0 && r <= 10
     then r
     else error "I don't know what I'm doing."
```